# Diamond Square improper implementation

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, javax.imageio, heightmap

Hello Stack Community,

I thought long and hard about posting this seeing as I did not want to attract yet another "duplicate" thread. However I have run out of ideas and do not know of any forums or other stacks where I could post this to get some help.

I wrote this application as a fun project in an attempt to generate some height-maps. However whenever I try to generate more than one height-map at a time all my duplicates appear as either black voids or if the *MAP_SIZE* variable is low enough white voids. (Example, 16 && 33 create white voids, 1025 creates black)

My output folder appears as follows: [low value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUaAH.png) vrs [higher value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcHV0.png)

[image: low value]

[image: high value]

Why is this? Is it simply a mathematical fluke that I am missing at 3:15 am?
I wrote the *printMap* specifically for the function of checking the values of the map data and while they are within ranges that would designate them to be black/white. I see no reason for this to exist continuously after the first iteration.

Just for fun I printed 44 more maps, and after the first one they all were black, *MAP_SIZE* was set at 1025. Feel free to check this out yourselves.

I created my diamond square algorithm based off my readings from here: [`http://www.gameprogrammer.com/fractal.html#heightmaps`](http://www.gameprogrammer.com/fractal.html#heightmaps)

And my greyWriteImage from a older stack overflow thread about simplex noise maps.

**EDIT**
Thanks to  I was able to solve my problem, turns out it was just a simple fact that for each new map you attempted to create using the *populateMap* function I forgot to reset avgOffset to 1. Essentially the problem was you were dividing the avgOffset continuously by 2 getting smaller and smaller results, which always which would always be cast a certain way.

Below I have included my completed source code for anyone who would like to work with my algorithm and output. Have fun.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class generateHeightMap {

    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43179809/diamond-square-improper-implementation

    private static final Random RAND = new Random();
    // Size of map to generate, must be a value of (2^n+1), ie. 33, 65, 129
    // 257,1025 are fun values
    private static final int MAP_SIZE = 1025;
    // initial seed for corners of map
    private static final double SEED = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 1 + 1);
    // average offset of data between points
    private static double avgOffSetInit = 1;

    private static final String PATH = "C:\\Users\\bcm27\\Desktop\\grayScale_export";
    private static String fileName = "\\grayscale_map00.PNG";

    public generateHeightMap(int howManyMaps) {
        System.out.printf("Seed: %s\nMap Size: %s\nAverage Offset: %s\n", 
                SEED, MAP_SIZE, avgOffSetInit);
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------");

        for(int i = 1; i <= howManyMaps; i++){ // how many maps to generate

            double[][] map = populateMap(new double[MAP_SIZE][MAP_SIZE]); 
            //printMap(map);         
            generateHeightMap.greyWriteImage(map);
            fileName = "\\grayscale_map0" + i + ".PNG";

            System.out.println("Output: " + PATH + fileName);
        }
    } 
    /*************************************************************************************
     * @param requires a 2d map array of 0-1 values, and a valid file path
     * @post creates a image file saved to path + file_name
     ************************************************************************************/
    private static void greyWriteImage(double[][] data) {
        BufferedImage image = 
                new BufferedImage(data.length, data[0].length, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        for (int y = 0; y < data[0].length; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < data.length; x++)
            {// for each element in the data

                if (data[x][y]>1){
                    // tells the image whether its white
                    data[x][y]=1;
                }
                if (data[x][y]<0){
                    // tells the image whether its black
                    data[x][y]=0;
                }
                Color col = // RBG colors
                        new Color((float)data[x][y],
                                (float)data[x][y],
                                (float)data[x][y]); 
                // sets the image pixel color equal to the RGB value
                image.setRGB(x, y, col.getRGB());
            }
        }

        try {
            // retrieve image
            File outputfile = new File( PATH + fileName);
            outputfile.createNewFile();
            ImageIO.write(image, "png", outputfile);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("I didn't handle this very well. ERROR:\n" + e);
        }
    }

    /****************************************************************************
     * @param requires map double[MAPSIZE][MAPSIZE]
     * @return returns populated map
     * 
     * [1] Taking a square of four points, generate a random value at the square 
     *     midpoint, where the two diagonals meet. The midpoint value is calcul-
     *     ated by averaging the four corner values, plus a random amount. This 
     *     gives you diamonds when you have multiple squares arranged in a grid.
     *
     * [2] Taking each diamond of four points, generate a random value at the 
     *     center of the diamond. Calculate the midpoint value by averaging the 
     *     corner values, plus a random amount generated in the same range as 
     *     used for the diamond step. This gives you squares again.
     *     
     *     '*' equals a new value
     *     '=' equals a old value
     *     
     *     * - - - *     = - - - =   = - * - =   = - = - =   = * = * =
     *     - - - - -     - - - - -   - - - - -   - * - * -   * = * = *       
     *     - - - - -     - - * - -   * - = - *   = - = - =   = * = * =
     *     - - - - -     - - - - -   - - - - -   - * - * -   * = * = *                
     *     * - - - *     = - - - =   = - * - =   = - = - =   = * = * =
     *         A             B           C           D           E
     *         
     *     A: Seed corners
     *     B: Randomized center value
     *     C: Diamond step
     *     D: Repeated square step
     *     E: Inner diamond step
     *     
     *     Rinse and repeat C->D->E until data map is filled
     *         
     ***************************************************************************/
    private static double[][] populateMap(double[][] map) {     

        // assures us we have a fresh map each time
        double avgOffSet = avgOffSetInit;

        // assigns the corners of the map values to SEED
        map[0][0] =
        map[0][MAP_SIZE-1] =
        map[MAP_SIZE-1][0] = 
        map[MAP_SIZE-1][MAP_SIZE-1] = SEED;

        // square and diamond loop start
        for(int sideLength = MAP_SIZE-1; sideLength >= 2; sideLength /=2,avgOffSet/= 2.0) {

            int halfSide = sideLength / 2;
            double avgOfPoints; 

            /********************************************************************
             *           [1]            SQUARE FRACTAL             [1]
             *********************************************************************/
            // loops through x & y values of the height map
            for(int x = 0; x < MAP_SIZE-1; x += sideLength) {
                for(int y = 0; y <MAP_SIZE-1; y += sideLength) {

                    avgOfPoints = map[x][y] +                 //top left point
                            map[x + sideLength][y] +            //top right point
                            map[x][y + sideLength] +            //lower left point
                            map[x + sideLength][y + sideLength];//lower right point

                    // average of surrounding points
                    avgOfPoints /= 4.0; 

                    // random value of 2*offset subtracted
                    // by offset for range of +/- the average
                    map[x+halfSide][y+halfSide] = avgOfPoints + 
                            (RAND.nextDouble()*2*avgOffSet) - avgOffSet;
                }
            }

            /********************************************************************
             *          [2]            DIAMOND FRACTAL           [2]
             *********************************************************************/
            for(int x=0; x < MAP_SIZE-1; x += halfSide) {
                for(int y = (x + halfSide) % sideLength; y < MAP_SIZE-1;

                        y += sideLength) {
                    avgOfPoints = 
                            map[(x - halfSide + MAP_SIZE) % MAP_SIZE][y] +//left of center
                            map[(x + halfSide) % MAP_SIZE][y] +           //right of center
                            map[x][(y + halfSide) % MAP_SIZE] +           //below center
                            map[x][(y - halfSide + MAP_SIZE) % MAP_SIZE]; //above center

                    // average of surrounding values
                    avgOfPoints /= 4.0; 

                    // in range of +/- offset
                    avgOfPoints += (RAND.nextDouble()*2*avgOffSet) - avgOffSet; 

                    //update value for center of diamond
                    map[x][y] = avgOfPoints;

                    // comment out for non wrapping values
                    if(x == 0)  map[MAP_SIZE-1][y] = avgOfPoints; 
                    if(y == 0)  map[x][MAP_SIZE-1] = avgOfPoints; 

                } // end y
            } // end x
        } // end of diamond
        return map;
    } // end of populateMap

    /*************************************************************************************
     * @param requires a 2d map array to print the values of at +/-0.00
     ************************************************************************************/
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static void printMap(double[][] map) {
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");     

        for (int x = 0; x < map.length; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < map[x].length; y++) {
                System.out.printf("%+.2f ", map[x][y] );              
            }
            System.out.println(); 
        }       
    }

} // end of class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible that `avgOffSet` must be initialized before creating each map (start of `populateMap`)?

It is being divided by 2 but never reset to 1. I suppose each map is independent, that is, does not depend on the previous one, so there is no reason to not reset the variable. But I do not know that algorithm and have no time to learn it... [:-|

```
private static double[][] populateMap(double[][] map) {

    avgOffSet = 1;  // missing this one

    map[0][0] = ...
```

if this is correct I would suggest that `avgOffset` should be a variable; eventually create a field `avgOffsetInitial` with the initial value (instead of the current field).

Comment: I added a description of the algorithm if you are curious. I guess my error was purely mathematical, probably could've waited to post this until after I had slept.

Comment: @bcm27 thanks, I must *play* with that algorithm sometime [:-)

Comment: no problem, I even updated my source code for you. Cheers